# jqGrid select row from code behind in c#?

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

Is there a way to select a jqGrid row in c# in the code behind?
In the code items are removed from the grid from a code behind process, so I'd like it to select the first row in the grid. 
I don't see something that i could easily call like SelectedIndex.

If anyone has suggestions that would be great. 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything in the documentation either. Since selecting a row is a client-side (JavaScript) operation rather than a data-oriented operation - which spans both client and server - it seems unlikely that this could be done via C# code-behind. I think you will need to write at least some JavaScript code to accomplish what you are trying to do.